# How to read Quarkus Config in dedicated Kotlin Class

Tags: kotlin, configuration, quarkus, inject

Reading application properties in Kotlin/Quarkus works in a test class likes this correctly (the print will write the value which are defined in the `application.properties` file):

```kotlin
@QuarkusTest
class Test {

    @ConfigProperty(name = "test.env")
    val testEnv: String? = null

    @Test
    fun test(){
        println(testEnv)
    }
}
```

But when I create a dedicated configuration class and try to access the member from that class, the value is always null (and not as defined in the `application.properties`):

```kotlin
class Config{
    
    @ConfigProperty(name = "test.env")
    val foo: String? = null
}
```

Trying to access this value in the test class (but the value is always null):

```kotlin
@QuarkusTest
class Test {

    @Test
    fun test(){
        println(Config().foo)
    }
}
```

Quarkus version: `1.10.3.Final`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@ConfigProperty` annotation is in fact a CDI qualifier. In Quarkus, if a field is annotated with a qualifier, it doesn't have to be annotated `@Inject` -- but it is treated as if it was.

So your test class is equivalent to this:

```kotlin
@QuarkusTest
class Test {
    @Inject
    @ConfigProperty(name = "test.env")
    val testEnv: String? = null

    @Test
    fun test(){
        println(testEnv)
    }
}
```

Now, the other important thing is that if possible, the Quarkus test framework treats the test class as a CDI bean. That is, the test class is instantiated by the CDI container, which performs dependency injection. That is how `testEnv` is populated.

How do you achieve the same thing?

1. Make your class a bean by adding a *bean defining annotation*.

```kotlin
@Singleton
class Config{ 
    @ConfigProperty(name = "test.env")
    val foo: String? = null
}
```

(Note that in standard CDI, `@Singleton` is not a bean defining annotation. In Quarkus, `@Singleton` *is* a bean defining annotation, but if you want to strictly adhere to the standard, you can use `@ApplicationScoped` instead.)

2. Don't instantiate `Config` by calling the constructor. Instead, use dependency injection again:

```kotlin
@QuarkusTest
class Test {
    @Inject
    Config config;

    @Test
    fun test(){
        println(config.foo)
    }
}
```